# incremented json keys, parsing CSV

Tags: php, json

I'm using mailparser.io to parse a .csv attachment and make an http post to another cloud service.  The problem is the json received is not an associative array but rather key values are incremented:

```
First_Name::1 = "John"
First_Name::2 = "Sally"
First_Name::3 = "Kenneth"
Last_Name::1 = "Smith"
Last_Name::2 = "Johnson"
Last_Name::3 = "Cline"
```

Using PHP, how can I reformat this into a usable json associative array and retain the index, something like:

```
{"Record":"1","First_Name":"John","Last_Name":"Smith"}
{"Record":"2","First_Name":"Sally","Last_Name":"Johnson"}
{"Record":"3","First_Name":"Kenneth","Last_Name":"Cline"}
```

The number of rows will vary, but the columns will always be the same.  So I assume I can count the number of key:value pairs and divide by the number of columns.  My example would provide 6 pairs, dividing by 2 columns would yield 3 sets.  Create an incremental loop and retrieve/build a usable json string.

```
$count = count($string);
$rows = $count/2;

$index = 0;
while($index <= $rows) {
    **get First_Name::1, Last_Name::1 and build json**
  $index++;
}
```

Yes, I realize mailparser will create an http post for each row in a csv, but it won't keep them in the original row order and I need to preserve that.

I've been able to tweak some settings in mailparser and now am receiving it as

```
"Record":[{"0":"John","1":"Smith"},
          {"0":"Sally","1":"Smith"},
          {"0":"Kenneth","1":"Cline"}
        ]
```

Comment: Then you are not receiving JSON from the first call. If you think you should be, check the parameters you use to call the first API

Comment: Is that data in a newline delimited string?

Comment: I probably have my terminology incorrect, but that's how it was being sent.  I've been able to tweak some settings in mailparser and now am receiving it as "Record":[{"0":"John","1":"Smith"},{"0":"Sally","1":"Smith"},{"0":"Kenneth","1":"Cline"}].  At least that's similar to the order in which I would expect to see the json and something I can probably reformat in PHP and post it individually to the third party cloud service.

Comment: :) Its not a very friendly API is it!

Comment: No, not at all.  One would assume mailparser would keep the csv rows in their original order, but that would make things easy wouldn't it?

Comment: That still isn't valid json content...

Comment: I realize it's not valid json content.  I have no hope of getting such from mailparser, all I'm trying to do is work with what I can get and extract the values then reformat them into proper json for sending to and endpoint.

Comment: Using:  

$record_raw = print_r((get_object_vars($decoded->Record['0'])), true);
$record = var_export($record_raw);

I'm able to get:

 'Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Smith
)
'

But I'm not able retrieve the value for [0]